# Maven artifact version number with custom variable

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have in my pom this section:

```xml
<groupId>com.sample.app</groupId>
<artifactId>simpleapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.9-${buildNumber}-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Is there any nice and "maven way" to keep this variable name ${buildNumber} in that place in pom as this is now?
I mean - when I am performing

```
mvn deploy:prepare deploy:release  -DbuildNumber=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

this version section in pom.xml is updated to (when BUILD_NUMBER eq: 12):

```xml
<version>1.0.9-12-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

which almost is ok but this is also commited to repository. I like the fact that this tag: 1.0.9-12 in git repo is created, but I prefer to keep my original format of version in `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<version>1.0.9-${buildNumber}-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

This is because this stupid approach I have in my company to add to artefact version also build number from CI tool :(

Can someone give me some hint how to handle this?

Comment: I did not completely understand your needs, but please have a look at [Maven CI Friendly Versions](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)

Comment: mvn deploy:prepare deploy:release  -DbuildNumber=123
will gives:  <version>1.0.9-123-SNAPSHOT</version> 
I want to have this line to looks as original: <version>1.0.9-${buildNumber}-SNAPSHOT</version>
and I do not want to provide version by hand.
This works perfectly for snapshot - because pom.xml file is not updated

Comment: mvn clean deploy -DbuildNumber=${BUILD_NUMBER} will produce artifact simpleapp-1.0.9-123-SNAPSHOT when BUILD_NUMBER=123
I have same artifact during release but pom is updated to value 1.0.9-124-SNAPSHOT which is incorrect because next BUILD_NUMBER can be totally different 
so I want to keep my format in pom.xml file - if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

The Maven Release Plugin has a parameter called  [`developmentVersion`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#developmentVersion) that allows you to set the new version that is committed to your git branch after the release is done.

If you want to tell the Release Plugin to reuse the parts of version you used before, the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) helps you to parse the version. It creates properties like `majorVersion` and `minorVersion` from which you can construct the target version you like.

Comment: Yes for the same I can just use step that reads in jenkins/tc pom values and invoke that from command line. I was wondering if there is a possibility to pass some extra params that deploy:release and perform could do the trick for me :-) Manually I know how to do that :D

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. `developmentVersion` is a parameter for `release:prepare` that allows you do set the future version in the branch. What else are you looking for?

Comment: in short - I just wanted execute release:perform release:prepare and have updated git repository but without updating pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I've added dependency for this helper plugin and final result is like this:

```
mvn --batch-mode \
build-helper:parse-version \
-DdevelopmentVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-\${parsedVersion.qualifier} \
-DreleaseVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}-31 \
release:clean \
release:prepare \
release:perform
```

I removed this ${buildNumber} as it is not required - Build Helper Plugin helped me a lot - I do not need any additional step in CI plan.
Now I have autoincrement and during release I am able to add build plan ID.

For me case solved :-)